# How to use SINTER and ZRANGEBYSCORE together in REDIS

Tags: redis, node-redis

Let's assume that there are three key pattern as `user:id`, `chat:id` and `message:date` that are used for to store data on sets.

Example data (completely fiction scenario):

```
sadd new:user:id 157
sadd new:user:id 282

sadd chat:id:10354 157
sadd chat:id:10354 282

zadd message:epoch:time 1488877701111 111
zadd message:epoch:time 1488898403636 282
zadd message:epoch:time 1488898409822 157
zadd message:epoch:time 1488899903333 333
```

I can find which new users had written messages each other on chat id `10354` by using the command of `SINTER chat:id:10354 new:user:id`.

Also I can find which users has written messages in between `1488880000000` and `1488899999999` by using the command of `ZRANGEBYSCORE message:epoch:time 1488880000000 1488899999999`.

**Question:**
Is there any chance to find the new users who had written messages in `chat:id:10354` in between `1488880000000` and `1488899999999`?

Comment: You can do this client-side or with a lua script: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/678 (even though it has its problems, read the thread).

Comment: @Niloct thank you. I've added `+1` comment to the issue. Gimene's workaorund is just like the solution which is in my workaround in my mind. But I won't use `lua` scripts.

Comment: @ekfan you're welcome. I used to intersect things in php client-side, that was really fast, perhaps not the fastest solution, but it managed `array_intersect`s with thousands of items.

Comment: @Niloct I've been testing `sinter` command and its alternative solutions for about 14 hours! A `sinter` operation that has two sets with total 1,500,000 keys has returned 500,000 records in 841 millisecond!

Comment: @ekfan Nice :) I found that `ZADD` was the bottleneck in my case. I had to fill the entire set on execution time, and I had about 2mi keys. What is the performance you got for node intersection ?

Comment: Sorry, @efkan...

Comment: @Niloct I'm in development phase still. And I'm a newbie :) If you might explain that what does `node intersection` stand for, I can try to answer. Redis I use, is on the same machine I code. No any redis cluster, network accessing lag or anything in my environment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137467/discussion-between-efkan-and-niloct).